# Generating random words in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

I would like to ask about how to make a program that should be generating three words with the length of 10 characters with first letter in uppercase and then those three words should merge so that only the first letter is in uppercase. There is a note that says to make the first letter in uppercase you should do toLowerCase and after that increase the first letter using substring.

Comment: No Language Tag - Seems `Java`!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and go through the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this feels kinda stupid but I did it.If the words have to be real then you will need something else.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class random {
public static void main(String[] args){
String word1=generateWord();

String word2=generateWord();

String word3=generateWord();

System.out.print(word1+"\n"+word2+"\n"+word3+"\n");

String allThreeWithTheFirstLetterCapital=putThemTogether(word1,word2,word3);

System.out.print(allThreeWithTheFirstLetterCapital);
}
   public static String generateWord(){
        Random r=new Random();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append((char)(65+r.nextInt(25)));
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        sb.append((char)(97+r.nextInt(25)));
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
public static String putThemTogether(String...strings){
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(strings[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<strings.length;i++){
        sb.append(strings[i].toLowerCase());
    }
    return sb.toString();}
}
```

this is it

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;


    public class weirdMath {

      public static void main(String[] args){
          double number1=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("input a first number"));
          double number2=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("input a second number")); 
          String operation=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("input an operation (+-/*)");
          number1*=2;number2*=2;
          double result=0;
          if(operation.equals("+")){result=number1+number2;}
          else if(operation.equals("-")){result=number1-number2;}
          else if(operation.equals("/")){result=number1/number2;}
          else if(operation.equals("*")){result=number1*number2;}
          JFrame jf=new JFrame("your answer");
          jf.setSize(300,75);
             Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
             int width = (int)screenSize.getWidth();
             int height = (int)screenSize.getHeight();
           jf.setLocation((int)(width/4.5), (int)(height/3.5));
          JLabel jlmessagepart1=new JLabel("       taking your two numbers times 2");
          JLabel jlmessagepart2=new JLabel("then performing your operation you get...");
          JLabel jlresult=new JLabel(""+result);
          jlresult.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 20));
          jlresult.setForeground(Color.blue);
          jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          jf.add(jlmessagepart1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
          jf.add(jlmessagepart2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
          jf.add(jlresult,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
          jf.setVisible(true);


      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have another assignment that I can't finish. It says: make a program that asks the user to enter two numbers and an operation (+,-,/,*). Both entered numbers first multiply by 2 and then perform the operation with the entered numbers obtained after multiplication. Note: Use If, and static methods.

Comment: does whoever you are doing these assignments care that i give you code?

Comment: here if you use this code I think your teacher will know you cheated so get the idea.use Scanner(Sytem.in);

Comment: This is too complicated for me. I posted the unfinished assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it is in Java (probably same for C?).

Look at Ascii table (http://www.asciitable.com/)

For the 1st Upper letter, generate a Integer between 65-90 and then make it to Character. For lower case generate a Integer between 97-122 and then make it to Character. Merge chars together to make a word.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
public Main() {
    double number1 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input first numnber:"));
    double number2 = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input second number:"));
    String operation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input operation +,-,/,*");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number1*2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number2*2);
    double result = 0;
    if (operation.equals("+")) {
        result = number1+number2;
  } else if (operation.equals("-")) {
        result = number1-number2;
  } else if (operation.equals("/")) {
        result = number1/number2;
  } else if (operation.equals("*")) {
        result = number1*number2;
  }
```

}
}

Comment: You did great that code is fine just use if and else if instead of the switch switching on Strings is new to java and requires newer java.

Comment: oh and I thought you needed to multiply a and b by 2 before the operation so System.out.println(a*2+b*2);

Comment: I did it how you told me, with if and else if but now it doesn't go through the operations +,-,/,*. I want it to execute the input operation but with the numbers obtained after multiplication by 2.

Comment: Never mind, I did it. I forgot to write System.out.println("The result is: " + result); Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: no problem hope you do well n your class.good luck.